# What is difference between "Direct form" and "Normal Direct form"?

Tags: filters, filter-design, infinite-impulse-response, digital-filters, terminology

What is difference between "Direct form" and "Normal Direct form"?
I was reading about filters implementations(structures) and found out both words "direct form"and "normal direct form" especially in proakis,2nd edition as shown highlighted in attached snapshot
[image]

Answer (score 2):

The modifier *normal* is meant to distinguish the form from the *transposed* form. So there is a *normal* direct form I, a *transposed* direct form I, and similarly for the direct form II. As far as I know, this terminology is not universal, and I've only come across it in books (co-)written by Manolakis or Ingle.